Decomposition of cohomology of Deligne-Lusztig varieties
Colloquially I've often heard that “one can construct” all representations of simple groups of Lie type in the cohomology of Deligne–Lusztig varieties. The technical way I've seen this written is as an analogue of parabolic induction when the maximal torus is not split.
My question is if we can phrase this as a decomposition result on the étale cohomology of the corresponding Deligne–Lusztig variety, i.e. do we know which representations of $G$ occur in which degree of the étale cohomology?

There is a large theory of cohomology of DL varieties. Roughly, there's a conjecture on the (unique) degree of cohomology for a unipotent character in some of the DL varieties $X(w)$ over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_\ell$, which has been proved for some $w,G$, has evidence in favour for other $w,G$. DL varieties end up being replaced by parabolic DL varieties for elements of the braid group in other versions of the theory, to allow for more information about reps to be found. What is still very open, even in theory, is the modular cohomology, so what's going on with the torsion in the cohomology.
